# ModuleNotFoundError when running a simple pytest

Tags: python, pytest

Python version 3.6

I have the following folder structure

```
.
├── main.py
├── tests/
|     └── test_Car.py
└── automobiles/
      └── Car.py
```

my_program.py

```
from automobiles.Car import Car

p = Car("Grey Sedan")
print(p.descriptive_name())
```

Car.py

```
class Car():
    description = "Default"
    
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.description = message

    def descriptive_name(self):
        return self.description
```

test_Car.py

```
from automobiles.Car import Car

def test_descriptive_name():
    input_string = "Blue Hatchback"
    p = Car(input_string)
    assert(p.descriptive_name() == input_string)
```

When running *pytest* in the commandline from the project root folder, I get the following error-

```
Traceback:
..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests\test_Car.py:2: in <module>
    from automobiles.Car import Car
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'automobiles'
```

I've been battling this for awhile now and I think I'm missing something obvious.
I don't think it is anything to do with a missing `__init__.py` - I've tried placing an empty `__init.py__` alongside the car.py file, with no difference in the error.

What do I have to change to get the `test_Car.py` to run successfully ?

Comment: Have you tried to add the current folder to your PYTHONPATH environment variable: `export PYTHONPATH='.'`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Run `python -m pytest` instead of `pytest`, which will also add the current directory to `sys.path` (see [official docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/usage.html#calling-pytest-through-python-m-pytest) for details).
2. Add a *__init__.py* file under *tests/*, then you can simply run `pytest`. This basically enables pytest to discover the tests if they live outside of the application code. You can find some more details about this in the [Tests outside application code](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/goodpractices.html?highlight=discover#tests-outside-application-code) section in the official docs.

Hope that helped!

Comment: Brilliant. Both options #1 and #2 worked.
@hans-bambel your suggestion worked as well. Thanks.

Comment: Nice to hear and glad I could help!